# Linq not adding data to table, using InsertOnSubmit() & SubmitChanges()

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using LINQ to insert data into the database. The problem is that after executing the code, the data isn't added into the table.

Here is what I do: 
Execute code → Go to "data connections" in server explorer → Refresh table.

But no row shows up in table.

Below is my code. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
    private static LinqToSqlDataContext dbContext;

    static Tables() //constructor
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MusicPlayerDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        dbContext = new LinqToSqlDataContext(connectionString);
    }

    public static void AddTrack(Track track) // Track is custom data structure
    {
        Track_Table trackTable = CreateTrack(track);
        dbContext.Track_Tables.InsertOnSubmit(trackTable);
        dbContext.SubmitChanges();
    }

    private static Track_Table CreateTrack(Track track)
    {
        Track_Table trackTable = new Track_Table
        {
            Track_Id = track.Id,
            Title = track.Title,
            Album_Id = null,
            Artist = track.Artist,
            Duration = track.Duration,
            Path = track.Path,
            Image_Path = track.imagePath
        };
        return trackTable;
    }
```

Comment: Does this table have a `primary key` ?

Comment: Yes. Track_Id is PK.

Comment: Are you getting an exception on save? Are you sure you are looking at the same database that you use for the code?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 dbContext.Track_Tables.InsertOnSubmit(trackTable); to
 dbContext.Track_Tables.Add(trackTable);
```

and then

```
 dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hmm. Context does not contain an add method... Table<Track_Table> does not contain a definition for Add.

Answer (score 0):

if you have this class:

```
public class Track
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Number {get; set;}
    public string Title{get; set;}
    // etc
}
```

Then your DbContext should look something like this:

```
public class MusicDbContext : DbContext // inherit from Entity Framework
{
    public DbSet<Track> Tracks{get;set;} // This maps to the database
}
```

This is really all you need. If your Database table is named "Tracks" then mapping will "just happen" and you now have a collection of tracks that you can use to update and add, delete (CRUD) with like so:

```
...
var myContext = new MusicDbContext();
myContext.Tracks.Add(theNewTrack);
myContext.SaveChanges();
...
```

**Important note**

Do NOT make a static variable of your DbContext class. Entity Framework keeps caches in it's own internal static objects, and if you try to persist your DbContext as a static, weird things will start happening after a few updates. Always new up the context. It is really fast after your first initial connect, and gives you cleaner code all over.

Comment: While I agree 100% on not keeping it as a static, _what makes you think this is EF_? `InsertOnSubmit` is a method of the `System.Data.Linq.Table<TEntity>` class, which makes this Linq 2 SQL. (edited:) And then there's the LinqToSqlDataContext which is a hint, too. :)

Comment: I see it now :) Something dirty in my coffee this morning!